# Escape characters in a text in Lua

Tags: string, sqlite, lua, escaping, coronasdk

In my SQlite3 database, I have a following VARCHAR data:

```
data = 'Kim okurdu kim yazardı \n Bu düğümü kim çözerdi \n Koyun kurt ile gezerdi \n Fikir başka başk\'olmasa'
```

And I try to display this text with:

```
local myText = display.newEmbossedText(data, globals.W/2,globals.H/2,300,300, native.systemFont, 16, { 1, 1, 1 } )
```

However, escape characters are not detected. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem with following line, thanks to Lerg from Corona community:

```
data:gsub([[\n]], '\n')
```

Comment: +1 So the \n in data was two characters rather than an escaped newline, good find, and thanks for posting answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is cleaner to escape a backslash with double backslash.
For example: `data:gsub ( "\\n", "\n" )`
Otherwise, you can use `load/loadstring` to parse any expression.
Example:

```
-- read in some a string with any kind of escapes, assuming a line-buffered input
myString = io.read()
-- load as function and call it
myString = loadstring ( "return "..myString )()
print ( myString )
```

However, the second method can be **very** unsafe, so use it carefully.